# Excel Problem, combining columns in a specific way

Tags: excel, logic, cell

I have a list of Materials composed of Sub components listed in 2 separate columns.

- One column  is composed of Materials  A, B and C.
- Another column shows the sub components of each of the ingredients.
- A is made up of sub ingredients `1-6`. B is made up of `7-13`. And C is made up of `14-21`(The numbers of ingredients/sub-ingredients does not matter as this can vary).

Importantly the two columns which contain the relevant data **are not adjacent** to one another (See attached image).

Is it possible to have a new column such that the data is automatically combines the relevant columns to read: `A,1,2,3,4,5,6,B,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,C,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21`, whilst omitting the columns in between.

In the attached image I have shown the desired output to better explain visually.

Progress so far has been achieved by help from @Gary's Student

- By having the columns A B adjacent to each other the desired output can be calculated with the following formula (with the column titles removed):
  =FILTERXML("**"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A:B:B),",","****")&"**","//b")
- The problem is that the standardised Excel spreadsheet that I am working on does not have these columns next to one another but instead the relevant data is in columns A and E respectively.
- Attempts to omit Columns B:D have been trailed using:
  =FILTERXML("**"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A,E:E)  ,",","****")&"**","//b") and although this does omit irrelevant  information, unfortunately this also changes the desired output to be `A,B,C,1,2,3...`

The attached image shows the desired output that I am trying to achieve from the material column and the sub component column whilst omitting the additional info.

Any further thoughts would be appreciated Thank you.

[image: EXCEL PROBLEM]

Comment: It would be best if you could show what you have tried yourself so far, e.g. a cell formula or VBA code.

Comment: Hi Apologise Im not hugely familiar with excel. I attempted this through using IF and ISBLANK Statements but could only get so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Excel 365** and data in columns **A** and **B**, in **C1** enter:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:B16),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If we want to include data from columns **A** and **E**, but exclude columns **B**, **C**, and **D**, then replace:

```
SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:B16)
```

with something like:

```
TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A,E:E)
```

**EDIT#2:**

Here is the correct equation:

```
=LET(x,INDEX(A$2:E$22,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(42)/2,0),IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(42),2)=0,5,1)),FILTER(x,x<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi again, although this does works well I actually created this as an example to simplify my question. In reality my document has the required data within column A  and column E only.   Can I achieve the same desired affect but excluding data within columns B,C,D. Thank you.

Comment: @iNick1  Let me think about it.

Comment: @iNick1  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Hey Gary. I did previously try to amend the formula as you have described to:  

=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A,E:E),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")

However this essentially combines the 2 lists as: ABC1234567 and not the desired output as shown in your above screenshot.

Comment: @iNick1  **Don't give up!**  I will continue to investigate.

Comment: @iNick1  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: Hi Gary When I use this equation I get a #NAME? error. I have copied it exactly as you have described and tested this on a new worksheet. Could you just check if what you send me is correct?

Comment: @iNick1  Sorry the equation is only valid for **Excel 365**